# How can I change the background of typography depending on their status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mern

How can I change the background of the text depending on the current value of the status?

So right now, the current status is `pending`, which defaulted to yellow.

Example: the value changes and it becomes `complete`. The background colour should change to green.

```
<Typography sx={{padding:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
       {recent.status}
</Typography>
```

This is what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: if it accepts adding some custom class, you can add it as a `className` and then style it in .css file .

Comment: i'm just doing inline style with it

Comment: May be you can have some lookup object with status as key and style object as value and based on the status you can check and it applies ... I meant `const lookup = {"pending" : {padding:1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}, "completed": {padding:1, backgroundColor: 'green'} }` and then while applying use this .... If required I would detail as an answer ... hope you got an idea 

Comment: can't you just use conditional inline styling? for example: `background: pending ? 'yellow' : 'green'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the status you have

Map status with color:

```js
const statusColor={
complete:'green',
pending:'yellow',
initiate:'blue',
}
```

And wherever you are getting this status value `recent.status`
use this

```
<Typography sx={{padding:1, backgroundColor: statusColor[recent.status]}}>
       {recent.status}
</Typography>
```